# Binding Canvas.Size to parent UserControl and then setting Canvas.Size in code

Tags: wpf

I have a wpf `Canvas` in a grid in a `UserControl` named 'root' and I bind the `Width` and `Height` of the canvas as follows:

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ActualWidth}"
Height="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

On the canvas all kinds of `DrawingVisual` are drawn.
In code behind I set the Width end Height of my Canvas equal to `ContentBounds.Right` and `ContentBounds.Bottom` so that every `DrawingVisual` that I add to the canvas will be visible.

This seems to work all right but I am confused about the binding mentioned.
This is a one-way binding from the usercontrol's actual size to the size of the canvas.

Does the setting of Width and Height in code behind overrule this binding?

When I remove the binding the canvas is displayed equally as well, but the control is also used in other places and situations and might be needed then.

Comment: You do NOT need to bind the canvas to its root size as it will always per default use all the space available from the parent in your case the canvas will always be as big as the grid in your usercontrol

Comment: Sounds very reasonable, I suppose the Binding was added to be sure it did, but apparantly is default behaviour. So how would the binding relate to code behind changes?

Comment: as soon as you set the parameter from code behind your binding is overwritten
you should not set parameters that are view related in code!
Maybe chack out a MVVM toutorial as WPF is designed to use MVVM

Comment: @DenisSchaf a graphical canvas with hunderds or thousands of objects using `DrawingContext` cannot be 100% MVVM, you will discover that you need to customize your canvas and a.o. you need a draw-event. Using wpf `Shapes` will not work performance-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the setting of `Width` and `Height` in code behind overrule this binding?

Yes. Programmatically setting the value of a target property that has a one-way binding applied to it will clear the binding.

Comment: With 'clear the binding' you mean the binding is actually removed or do you mean it is overriden but still exists?

Comment: @Gerard: It's removed.